# How to make Carousel without autoplay in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, carousel

In my appliation I am trying to implement Carousel ,but that shuold not move automatically when user touch the it should move .
Below is the refrence what I have to biuld . In this Carousel  I have to display the dots , liks if there is 5 image then 5 dots should cpme below of that .
It is same like below link . Please help

https://xd.adobe.com/spec/5a3400b7-9e6e-4ae0-4f5c-dcb98ae4242e-2c05/

```
import ImageCarousel from 'react-native-image-page';

<ImageCarousel
 autoplay={false}
 height={100}
 indicatorSize={10}
   indicatorOffset={-120}
   indicatorText="*"
   indicatorColor="blue"
    images={this.img}
   />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel). It has built-in [autoplay](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/blob/master/doc/PROPS_METHODS_AND_GETTERS.md#autoplay) . You can enable or disable it.

Comment: Thanks , I saw this .. There are many examples , I have to get that which has below dots

Comment: Try this [pagination](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/blob/master/doc/PAGINATION.md)

Comment: This should be more of a comment than an answer - if you are going to provide links in your answer then the majority of the content should be copied here so that the answer will still make sense if the link dies in future

Comment: @Pete I agree .